# Why is my path to value wrong - I get null

Tags: android, firebase

I have the following data base:

```
database
    |
    places
       |  
       |____user1
       |      |_____outside: "yes"
       |
       |____user2
              |_____outside: "no"
```

I am fetching the data like that:

```
mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("places");

ValueEventListener placesListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {                
                for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    //this won't work
                    String place = datas.child("user1").child("outside").getValue().toString();

            }
mDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(placesListener);
```

But it doesn't work, when I launch my app, I get that it is a null and the app crashes.

Log crash, as requested:

```
Process: com.example.places, PID: 32431
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.places.MainActivity$1.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:44)
    at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzap.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.3:75)
    at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzca.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.3:63)
    at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzcd$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.3:55)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: post your crash log plz, and add `if(dataSnapshot.exists())` before you start foreach

Comment: Thank you, I will add. Also added the crash log

Comment: after you add check it crashes?

Comment: Have you tried logging your for loop values? You are running through and at some point it will not have user1 in it 

dataSnapshot.getChildren() --> Is going over user1 and user2

Comment: try this in your for loop and log it. datas.child("outside").getValue().toString();

Comment: You're right, I then have to move this line above the for loop and it works! You rock (It's a data I need once anyway, and not for every loop, so getting this value once above the for loop works!)

Comment: Glad that it works, i will post an answer with detailed information, so others who might have the problem can see :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dataSnapshot.getChildren()` currently iterates over all children in your "places"

Currently you have `user1` and `user2`.

When you iterate over them in a for loop like you are doing

```
String place = datas.child("user1").child("outside").getValue().toString();
```

You will eventually try to look for datas.child("user1") when it does not exist.

in the for loop you can use

```
datas.child("outside").getValue().toString();
```

If you log this you will find first `user1` outside value printed, and then `user2`.

If you need user1 you can add an if statement where you check the key

```
if(datas.getKey().toString().equals("user1"))
```

Then do what you need. `user1` should not be hardcoded, but a parameter that fetches the user you need.